# php gd is returning black background and the image creator function return images in the center of the page

Tags: php, html, php-gd

I am working with PHP-GD.When i try to create image using "imagecreatetruecolor" function in PHP the image is generated.But the main problem here is the image thus generated has a black background as specified in the code but the rest of the whole page also turns grey and the image is displayed at the center of the window regardless of the attributes given in the imagecreatetruecolor function.I have been working since four months on PHP-GD it never happened to me. But form the last week its behaving awkward.Please help me to solve.

```
<?php

header("Content-type: image/png");

$img = imagecreatetruecolor(400, 400);

$white = imagecolorallocate($img, 255, 255, 255);
$red   = imagecolorallocate($img, 255,   0,   0);
$green = imagecolorallocate($img,   0, 255,   0);
$blue  = imagecolorallocate($img,   0,   0, 255);

imagefilledellipse($img,100,100,10,10,$green);
imagefilledellipse($img,200,200,10,10,$green);

imagepng($img);

imagedestroy($img);

?>
```

[image: This is the output when i try to execute the above code.As you see the image i created using php gd functions returns a image at the center of the window rather than attributes added to the function imagecreatetruecolor]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the result of Chrome and not GD. The latest version of Chrome centers the image in your window and gives the rest of the window a black background.

If you want to see this in actions, add the following code to give your image a white background:

```
imagefill($img, 0, 0, $white);
```

Which will give you the following:

[image]

Comment: Cant we resolve this?? the problem i am facing is i cant understand the image size and when i try to save the image it is saved in the format of php file.

Comment: Thanks for u answer @niraj shah .It worked as previous in internet explorer and the answer you provided about chrome help me.